A datagram of more than 1600 bytes cannot be transmitted from a specific PC
There is a situation where more than 1600 bytes cannot be transmitted from a specific PC.
This is the code I used
private static UdpClient udpMachine1 = new UdpClient(5102);
int k = udpMachine1.Send(data, data.lenth);
The K value returned is the size of data
Is there any way to solve this?

You're lucky you got that many. The total size of an Ethernet packet is abou 1500 bytes, ad you have to subtract the Ethernet frame overhead, the IP packet overhead, and the UDP datagram overhead to get the maximum practical UDP payload without fragmentation. If a UDP datagram gets fragmented and a fragment is lost the entire datagram is lost. The generally accepted non-fragmenting limit for UDP payloads is 534 bytes.
